# how to access react-konva “stage” or “layer” from event handler?

Tags: react-konva

How would one access the “stage” or “layer” from an event hanlde when using react-konva? (i.e. with JSX)

For example in this example: https://konvajs.org/docs/react/index.html, how would one access stage or layer in the event handler if one wanted to do a “find”, to search for a particular canvas node…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
onClick={(e) => {
   const stage = e.target.getStage();
   const layer = e.target.getLayer();
}}
```

Comment: thanks - actually if you didn't have an "event" how would get access to Layer say?   I'm just noting when I'm using the "dragBoundFunc" for a Group it actually don't have an event object to pick this up from?

Comment: PS.  I did actually separately post a different (but related question) here if you're interested - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628119/getting-react-konva-context-in-a-parent-handler-is-there-a-better-way-than-my.  thanks